# convert nested for loop to linq with condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How to convert below c# nested for loop to linq...?

```
 list = objBLForms.GetForms(Ids);
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (list[i].StateId == list[j].StateId && 
                    list[i].PayerId == list[j].PayerId && i != j)
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(list[i].Tax))
                        {
                            list.Remove(list[i]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            list.Remove(list[j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I want to Remove duplicate payers with same state..And if any state tax is present, i wanted to remove the other duplicate one i,e; the duplicate one which is having no state tax...
I have achived it by using the nested for loop as shown above.
is there any way to do it in linq..I dont't know anything about linq.
Am very new to linq,Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that `&& i != j` isn't needed: just start `j` at 1 rather than 0.

Comment: yes,@john..that's a good idea!

Comment: Both for loops start at 0 and both end at `Count`. You are bound to compare an object to its own self

Comment: yes @ahmmed.. i wanted to remove duplicates, so i need to compare to its own self only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems about right to me:

```
list =
    list
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Tax)
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.StateId, x.PayerId })
        .SelectMany(x => x.Take(1))
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic of your code is actually removing EVERYTHING that has `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Tax)`, and only keeping first record that has value in `Tax`. Then, how about this

```
list
    .Where(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l.Tax))
    .GroupBy(l => new {l.StateId, l.PayerId})
    .Select(group => group.First())
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: it removing every item where tax is empty...but only remove empty tax item when there exist an other duplicate item with tax, else keep that empty tax item in the list